# When sharing a link to a question or answer, you can delete the highlighted text

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, sharing

After opening the Share popup, you can delete or otherwise edit the input field - should it be readonly?

Comment: I agree. Seems like a no-brainer change to make. (Removing your user ID after the fact can be done outside of that field, at least until the team finally relents and provides a second field without the user ID or a checkbox to toggle it in just the one field...)

Comment: [Dupe on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272770/share-text-box-is-editable)

Comment: From the dupe, I find this resonates with me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272770/share-text-box-is-editable#comment886007_272770

Comment: @D_N I find this resonates with me more: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272770/share-text-box-is-editable#comment886116_272770

Comment: I find this resonates with me most: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272770/share-text-box-is-editable#comment886098_272770 (this is fun, guys!)

Comment: The Ctrl+Z reasoning is stupid. Let's make literally everything that's not intended to be edited editable because we can just undo any accidental changes.